# Small gap in very right side of window (window oversize)

Tags: javascript, css, electron, chromium

i just started to make a new app by electron and find out after adding a new feature in my app, a very hard to notice white(or maybe transparent) gap added in very right side of the window. 
More explanation: I made an application that fetch something from server and after some manipulation, will display them in main window. The application just has 1 window (its quite simple app) and this is configuration for window that i added into main js "**Before**" gap shows up:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show      : false,
    width     : 820,
    height    : 520,
    frame     : false,
    resizable : false,
    title     : "blah blah blah"
})
```

After that i decided to expand the app and cache last location of the window before user try to close window so in next time that user will open the app, the window will at the same prev place. So i added some extra function to catch window "x" and "y" and save them into a "json" file in "appData". I changed window config to this one:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show      : false,
    width     : 820,
    height    : 520,
    frame     : false,
    resizable : false,
    title     : "blah blah blah",
    x         : {get x from storage},//this is pseudo 
    y         : {get y from storage}//this is pseudo 
})
```

Now a small gap appears in right side as shown in pictures below. More explanation in pictures caption.

**HTML**:

```
<body>
    <div class="hello-rob">
        <div class="nav"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**:

```
body,
html {
    position: relative;
    width: 820px;
    font-weight: normal;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

[image: x_y_and_css_and_gap]
**caption**: Css width set to "820px" same as window "width" in `main. js`, as you can see there is almost "2-3px" white gap (i marked with a circle)

[image: comment_css_width]
**caption**: If i comment the css width, then the window will expand to its real width that is "**822.4px**"

[image: x_y_comment]
**caption**: When i comment "x" and "y" in `main.js` and `css` "width" presence, every thing seems fine.

**P.S**: i don't think this issue its just about "x" and "y" that set in `main.js` and regardless of that the main problem is:

> Why and how the window is bigger than what we set for it in `main.js` and in `css`?

- electron v1.7.11
- Windows 10 64bit

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for down vote, i assume you just wanted say something and give down vote, right? My friend none of these images shown any error/errors, actually they are just for clarify. Everything that a real helper "not you" most know are available as text. How can i draw a gap with text? You ever saw i mention there is an error? That's why i didn't include my console because there is no error. And bottom of my question is about "x" & "y" that i mentioned as code in top. So remove images, nothing will happen to my real question

Comment: @Rob This is not at all pertinent in this question. The question is well written and complete and the images are essential for the display of the issue. Please do not blindly vote down and comment questions with images in them!

Comment: Where is the HTML and CSS to complete this question? @mplungjan

Comment: @Rob This is electron issue my professional friend :)

Comment: Where is the HTML and CSS to complete this question?

Comment: @Rob those who can answer this will likely know from the example code where the problem lies. If Colin can provide us with a [mcve] that would be great, but I assume that is difficult since it is a server framework creating the code. In any case the images are useful

Comment: @Rob The problem is why **electron** draw window bigger than what we limited for it by **javascript**

Comment: @mplungjan Please read my first comment so I don't need to repeat it for you here.

Comment: @Rob I read it. As you can see I have been around SO for a while. This is not a "here is a picture of my code and errors, fix them" question

Comment: @ColinCline Can you possibly show some rendered HTML with CSS that shows the issue?

Comment: @mplungjan Ofc, but i am sure all professional/non-professional programmer will find out they are not part of problem. I will update soon

Comment: It would be great to see what the content of x and y was. Perhaps it is a string where it should be an int?

Comment: I don't know how to answer the question but I know you can set `useContentSize` on the browser window and it will scale to whatever size the web page is.

Comment: setBounds seems to be interesting too. Also as I expected x/y needs to be ints: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#user-content-class-browserwindow

Comment: @mplungjan They are int and successfully store and restore by "fs" `node.js`. And app will move by them in initial opening. Problem is why electron draw window with "2.4" extra pixel when windows is not in center of OS

Comment: @mplungjan @Mike Tried all of these so far: `useContentSize: true`, `minWidth: 820`, `maxWidth: 820`, `minHeight: 520`, `maxHeight: 520` and `setBounds({width:820, height: 520})` when window trys to update size/after move and no success (gap still exist). Sound like bug i guess. Thx for your suggestion @mplungjan @Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please note**:

1. This is not a "permanent solution", this is just a temporary hotfix before electron team diagnose what is the main cause of this behavior by `electron.js`.
2. Thanks to [@mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) and [@Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6577664/mike) to reminding me to read documentation once again

I tried to watch/trace "window size" in every moment so that i can find out inside the electron core "window size" is inaccurate or no, something in `renderer.js` is involve?!

Based on this results (from `main.js`), its obvious changes happen in `main.js` part.

This is `main.js` console (when extra gap is evident):

```
[ 823, 522 ]// console.log(mainWindow.getSize());
[ 822, 521 ]// console.log(mainWindow.getContentSize());
{ x: 680, y: 101, width: 823, height: 522 }// console.log(mainWindow.getBounds());
```

From the results you can see electron uses `setSize`, `getSize` to demonstrate window size and obviously its not accurate because the window's size should be "820px" * "520px".

**How to fix this**: (*please consider big part of codes below are not new, new tricky-lines has a comment*)

```
function createWindow(){
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        show      : false,
        width     : 820,
        height    : 520,
        frame     : false,
        resizable : false,
        title     : "blah blah blah",
        x         : {get x from storage},//this is pseudo 
        y         : {get y from storage}//this is pseudo 
        minWidth: 820,// new
        maxWidth: 820,// new
        minHeight: 520,// new
        maxHeight: 520// new
    })

    // in this function i called console.log()
    mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        mainWindow.show();
        mainWindow.setSize(820,520);// new (i didn't checked but maybe before `mainWindow.show();` is better to place this line of code)
    })
}


app.on('ready', () => {
    createWindow()
})
```

Another test to check the effect of changes:

```
[ 820, 520 ]// console.log(mainWindow.getSize());
[ 820, 520 ]// console.log(mainWindow.getContentSize());
{ x: 680, y: 100, width: 820, height: 520 }// console.log(mainWindow.getBounds());
```

And the gap no longer exists.
**P.S**: personally i don't like this kind of solutions, so if any one else was able to represent a better solution i'll accept it as an answer.